# JavaMail with Gmail: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am receiving error when I try to send a mail using JavaMail API and I am sure that the username and password are 100% correct.
The Gmail account which I'm connecting is an older account, because they say it takes time for it to work with new accounts.

Error being received:

```java
DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

535 5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 x35sm3011668
wfh.6

javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
        javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
        at Main.<init>(Main.java:41)
        at Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

...and this is my code:

```java
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
 
public class Main
{
    String  d_email = "abc@gmail.com",
            d_password = "pass",
            d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            d_port  = "465",
            m_to = "abc@gmail.com",
            m_subject = "Testing",
            m_text = "testing email.";
    
    public Main()
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
 
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
 
        try
        {
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            session.setDebug(true);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setText(m_text);
            msg.setSubject(m_subject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to));
            Transport.send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception mex)
        {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main blah = new Main();
    }
 
    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator
    {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(d_email, d_password);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @bobby: The base64 encoded value of your password was visible in the original post. I've removed it one hour ago, but it's still visible in edit history. I strongly recommend you to change your Gmail password before a malicious hacker may break your Gmail account.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The given code snippet works fine on my Gmail account, so this problem lies somewhere else. Did you follow [the link given in the error message](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257)? It contains the following hints:

> - Make sure that you've entered your full email address (e.g. username@gmail.com)
> - Re-enter your password to ensure that it's correct. Keep in mind that passwords are case-sensitive.
> - Make sure your mail client isn't set to check for new mail too often. If your mail client checks for new messages more than once every 10 minutes, your client might repeatedly request your username and password.

Especially the last point is important. Google is very strict in this. If you're trying to connect Gmail for example more than 10 times in a minute programmatically, then you may already get blocked. Have a bit of patience, after some time it will get unblocked.

If you'd like more freedom in sending mails, I recommend to look for a dedicated mail host or to setup your own mail server, such as Apache James or Microsoft Exchange. I've already [answered this in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957299/how-do-i-configure-a-mail-server-for-use-with-javamail/2957332#2957332) in one of your previous questions.

Comment: hhey thanks...it worked..!!can u tell me how to send a mail using jsp..!!im trying to implement 'forgot password' in a website are there any ideas and suggessions from u to implement this..!!

Comment: Just create a servlet class which does the task and create a HTML form in JSP which submits to the URL where this servlet is listening on. In the servlet method you can just write and call real Java code the usual way. Learn more about JSP/Servlet here: http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html

Comment: @simplyblue hey can you please help me out,how it worked for you,i am struggling with the same issue,please help

Answer (score 54):

I had same issue :
I refer this [link](https://www.concretepage.com/questions/326), I have followed below steps it worked for me.

By default Gmail account is highly secured. When we use gmail smtp from non gmail tool, email is blocked.  To test in our local environment, make your gmail account less secure as

1. Login to Gmail.
2. Access the URL as https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
3. Select "Turn on"

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. I thought the issue was with my code and username and password; but this actually solved the problem. i think Gmail has been updating security configs.

Comment: This solution unfortunately will be outdated soon as Google announced that "On May 30 2022 Google will no longer support the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password. Instead, you’ll need to sign in using Sign in with Google or other more secure technologies, like OAuth 2.0. Learn more". Practically, the option Less Secure apps will be unavailable from May 30 and later..

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the exact same problem, for me the reason is I have turned on [2-step verification](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744) on my gmail account.

After generating a new application-specific password and use that in my java application, this "535 5.7.1" issue is gone.

You can generate a new application-specific password following this [official google guide](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833).

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem although my username and password were correct, but after some research, I was able to send email through applications by enabling the ***Less secure app access*** option on my Gmail account. You can find this feature under [security](https://myaccount.google.com/security) option in the left menu.

Related links:

- [I can't sign in to my email client](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=636952208424980116-3762560008&rd=1#cantsignin)
- [Enable access to less secure applications](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Answer (score 4):

**Now, Google not supported Less Secure Apps so we are getting this issue.
You follow bellow steps to resolve your Authentication issue during send mail using SMTP.**

1 - Enable 2-step Verification in your mail
2 - Once you enabled above, you will able to see App Passwords option in same Security tab
3 - Now generate App Password for Other(Custom)
4 - Use this generated password in place of your gmail password in your code.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error message and this is how I have solved the issue,

Create an app password: here is how we can generate an app password,

```
1. Visit your App passwords page. You may be asked to sign in to your Google Account.

2. At the bottom, click Select app and choose the app you’re using.
Click Select device and choose the device you’re using.

3. Select Generate.

4. Follow the instructions to enter the App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar) on your device.

5. Select Done.
```

I worked for a  Spring boot app and I get the app password say, `sadsadaffferere` for the email address, `xyz@gmail.com`. So, I need to configure the app properties like the following,

```
# the email settings
# ------------------
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=xyz@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=sadsadaffferere
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
support.email=xyz@gmail.com
```

Everything works fine afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on the 'less secure apps allowed' in gmail settings.

Comment: Right, but from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports this option

Answer (score 0):

If the same credential was working earlier and it stopped working then the primary reason for this problem is password mismatch/changed on gmail client and not updated in Jenkins or other CI server. If that is not the case then check for reasons mentioned by @BalusC

Answer (score 0):

i turned off antivirus and enabled less secure app in gmail, but now google has disabled this option, for that to work you need to do two steps verification and genetare 16 digit password and paste in application.properties replace this 16 digit password.