# SMTP authentication error while connecting to Gmail with oAuth2/JavaMail in web app

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail

I am able to run Google's sample code for Gmail IMAP/SMTP using JavaMail with oAuth on cmdline (OAuth2Authenticator.java from http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/)

But the same code doesn't seem to work for SMTP (IMAP works fine) in the web app on tomcat. It throws

> 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>   535 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257

Any idea, why this doesn't work for SMTP alone on web app?

Comment: Check this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965251/javamail-with-gmail-535-5-7-1-username-and-password-not-accepted

Comment: Thanks. Saw this already. But, this seems to be a different problem. The same stuff works on the cmd line consistently. But not on tomcat. Should be an environment issue.
As of now, I am running SMTP alone from a custom written web server from cmd line.

Comment: I also tried it, doesn't work. Did you solved it? I also want to connect to outlook.com by OAuth. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440163.aspx