# why I can send email by gmail in my local, but can not send be ubuntu server?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have using JavaMail version 1.4.3, I can sent email in my dev environment, but can not sent email when deploy in ubuntu server.
I compare the debug log as below:smtp can not be accepted but my local can.any suggestings? I also search here [java mail error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965251/javamail-with-gmail-535-5-7-1-username-and-password-not-accepted)

```
local:

    **DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.3
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP u9sm646165paf.22 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465
EHLO 10.37.129.2
250-mx.google.com at your service, [112.64.93.195]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 



ubuntu:

DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.3
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP ed8sm502698qeb.7 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465


WkFRITJ3c3hjZGUz
535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 ed8sm502698qeb.7 - gsmtp
15:21:33,167 ERROR ~

@6e0gki7nd
The email has not been sent

Mail error
A mail error occured : Error while sending email

play.exceptions.MailException: Error while sending email
        at play.libs.Mail$2.call(Mail.java:186)
        at play.libs.Mail$2.call(Mail.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:25
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)
        at play.libs.Mail$2.call(Mail.java:183)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 ed8sm502698qeb.7 - gsmtp

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:648)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:583)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you think you're using the same username and password in both cases, but you're not.

Note that the funny text after "AUTH LOGIN" is your base64 encoded username and **password**.  Anyone can decode them.  Without decoding them I can tell you that they're not the same in both cases, probably because you've altered the debug output in some way.

Check your program and make sure you're really using the same username and password in both cases.

Comment: Billl, thanks for your response.
I have manually modified the username and password below..
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6xxxcc
YXBwbHlmdWw=xxxcc
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6xxxcc
WkFRITJ3c3hjZGUzxxxcc
235 2.7.0 Accepted**

actually i add xxxcc above

Comment: Note that adding "xxxcc" doesn't prevent people from decoding that and seeing your password.

Comment: For the benefit of other people who might have a similar problem, exactly **what** Gmail configuration issue caused the problem?

Comment: If new client want to use your gmail account, gmail ask to login and do a validation, after that, the new client can use it.