# Having issues with my email

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm having trouble using my code below for an email in on of my programs. 
I'm getting this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u15sm14739609wrc.10 - gsmtp

```
at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:36)
```

Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u15sm14739609wrc.10 - gsmtp

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:932)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:843)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:748)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:31)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail {

   public static void main(String [] args) {    

   final String username = "ae513309@mail.com"; //sender's email
   final String password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";//sender's password

   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //This is the smtp server address
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");//This is the port for the smtp server

   Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
           return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
       }
   });

   try{
       Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("ae513309@mail.com")); //from sender's email address
       message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("be513309@mail.com")); //to receivere's email address
       message.setSubject("Module Registration"); //Sets the subject of the email
       message.setContent("You're selected modules have been registered","text/html; charset=utf-8");//sets the body of the email
       Transport.send(message);//sends the entire message object

       System.out.println("Email was sent!");
   }
   catch (MessagingException fnfe){
       throw new RuntimeException(fnfe);//if the email address is bad or doesn't exist
   }       
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to post the password, don't you think?

Comment: @RC. Well, I guess its a mock password like `admin123`

Comment: @Humberd let's hope so, the "t" prefix is unusual

Comment: => OP, did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965251/javamail-with-gmail-535-5-7-1-username-and-password-not-accepted?rq=1 ?

Comment: @RC. It's a real account I just created. The email works. Password is correct too. I've read that question, still stuck on it though :(

Comment: Are you really posting your credentials on the internet, open for everyone,   and further on confirm that the credentials are valid and usable? Please stop using the internet!!!

Comment: @baao it's a test email. I just created it to test the code above. My credentials have not been put in the creation of the email. It's brand new.

Comment: Got it to work guys :) thanks soo much :) thanks @RC. you're the best :)

Comment: I did nothing, but OK (NB: I did vote to close as "can no longer be reproduced", maybe I should have closed it as a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

=> OP, did you read [JavaMail with Gmail: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965251/javamail-with-gmail-535-5-7-1-username-and-password-not-accepted?rq=1) ? – @RC.

Thanks @RC. :) I used the code in the link and tweaked a few things in it :)