# JavaMail API : Username and Password not accepted (Gmail)

Tags: java, authentication, gmail, jakarta-mail

I want to send email from my java application to gmail account I used the following code and javaMail API ,But Gmail not accepted username and password and exception thrown 
Can anybody help me how can I fix this issue?

**MailService.java**

```
public class MailService {

    String email;
    String content;
    public void sendMail(String email,String content)
    {
        this.email=email;
        this.content=content;
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
          String to = email;

          // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
          String from = senderemail@gmail.com;
          final String username = "myusername";//change accordingly
          final String password = "*******";//change accordingly

          // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
          String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

          // Get the Session object.
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
             new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
           }
             });

          try {
           // Create a default MimeMessage object.
           Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

           // Set From: header field of the header.
           message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

           // Set To: header field of the header.
           message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                   InternetAddress.parse(to));

           // Set Subject: header field
           message.setSubject("Did you get my message?");

           // Now set the actual message
           message.setText(content);

           // Send message
           Transport.send(message);

           System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

          } catch (MessagingException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaMail with Gmail: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965251/javamail-with-gmail-535-5-7-1-username-and-password-not-accepted)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be able send mail messages via your gmail account, you should allow unsecure applications (which your application is by gmail's point of view) in google account security settings.
[image]

UPD:
Also, if you want to see debug messages, use next java mail property:

```
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
```

It can help you to find out what happening behind the scenes.

Comment: This and many related topics are covered in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmailauth).

Answer (score 3):

You can try to allow unsecure applications, it worked for me.

Steps for Gmail account :

1. Sign in to Gmail
2. [Click here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) to access Less Secure App Access in My Account.
3. Next to “Allow less secure apps: OFF,” select the toggle switch to
   turn ON.

See [this link](https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/) for Gmail and G-Suite.