# Exception: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified? Even with PasswordAuthenticator?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am making a java application that sends emails.

For some reason, I kept getting `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`, even though I have the correct username and password.

I've seen some posts say that the missing password authentication might cause this exception as well, but I think i have that part as well. Now I am so stuck and couldn't figure out where things go wrong.

here is my code:

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.*;

public class sendEmail {
    private static String subject = "Test", content = "This is a test";

    public sendEmail() {

    }

    public static void send() throws MessagingException{
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");// set the authentication to true
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
        String username = "clashroyale70532@gmail.com";
        String password = "********";
        Session ses = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPassWordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
        ses.setDebug(true);
        Message message = prepareMessage(ses,username);
        Transport.send(message);
    }

    private static Message prepareMessage(Session session, String account) {
        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(account));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(account));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setText(content);
            return msg;
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException m) {
            throw new RuntimeException(m);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            sendEmail.send();
            }
            catch (MessagingException m) {
                m.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Here is the JavaMail debug output:

```
 DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
    DEBUG: getProvider() returning 
    javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
    DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
    DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=*******(name not shown, it's my real name), password=<null>
```

The user it shows is not associated with the email account I used in my code. I am not sure how it got my real name.

Comment: it seems your issue is with gmail server setting  check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406528/javamail-api-username-and-password-not-accepted-gmail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaMail with Gmail: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965251/javamail-with-gmail-535-5-7-1-username-and-password-not-accepted)

Comment: I turn on less secured app access already. I think this is a different problem because: 1. diffrent error name; 2. I have successfully sent some emails using ssl instead of smtp with the same account

Comment: You mean SMTP *over* SSL surely?

Comment: Yeah, I found a tutorial online that uses SSL and I sent out emails successfully with that method. It doesn't work when I change everything to smtp, as i followed another tutorial.

Comment: Let me see if I understand... If you us SMTP over SSL, it works, but if you use SMTP without SSL (which I presume you mean that you're depending on the STARTTLS option as in your code above), it doesn't work.  Can you post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) for the case that doesn't work?  And if you have a configuration that works, why don't you just use it?

Comment: I am new to java. Learning and understanding are my main focus. I really want to know what is causing the problem instead of just skip it without fully understand it.  I included the JavaMail debug output. At the end of the debug output, it supposed to be "...password=<null>"  Not sure why it's not showing in the question part.