# Is it possible to send e-mails with GMail API using user name and password only?

Tags: java, email, gmail, gmail-api

I was told by a colleague that using the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/gmail/v1) library, you can send e-mails from corporate Gmail account with user name and password.

So far I could not find out how exactly I can build an instance of the [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.html) with user name and password (no access token, no secret).

Is it at all possible to use GMail API for sending e-mails with just user name and password? If so, where can I find an example?

**Update 1:** When I use the following code

```
@Test
fun sendMail() {
    val credentials = Properties()
    credentials.load(FileInputStream("src/test/resources/credentials.properties"))

    val username = credentials.getProperty("username")
    val password = credentials.getProperty("password")

    val prop = Properties()
    prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com")
    prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587")
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true")
    prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true") //TLS

    val session = Session.getInstance(prop,
            object : javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
                    return PasswordAuthentication(username, password)
                }
            })

    try {

        val message = MimeMessage(session)
        message.setFrom(InternetAddress("..."))
        message.setRecipients(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("...")
        )
        message.setSubject("Testing Gmail")
        message.setText("Hello!!")

        Transport.send(message)

        println("Done")

    } catch (e: MessagingException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>   535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials n6sm4681584wmn.48 - gsmtp

Comment: Your problem was reported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965251/javamail-with-gmail-535-5-7-1-username-and-password-not-accepted

Comment: I'm sure you'll have to do: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: take a look at Step 2 here : http://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828 it suggests that you might need to enable POP on the GMail account first, which might include SMTP.

Comment: Also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13986154 in the question linked suggest that you should check if you have [2-step verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) enabled on this account.

Comment: check if the option "allow insecure apps access" (something like that) im your gmail account is on: by default google will block the mail from your app. Hope it helps: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it is not going with gmail api. It's basic mail server configuration for JMS. Here is what i did at spring;

Configuration file:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=[GMAIL_USERNAME]
spring.mail.password=[GMAIL_PASSWORD]
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Java code with using JavaMailSender:

```
@Component
public class EmailService
{
    @Autowired
    protected JavaMailSender emailSender;

    public void sendRegistrationMail(RegistrationForm form) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(form.getUserMail());
        message.setSubject("-- COOL SUBJECT --");
        message.setText("- COOL TEXT -");
        emailSender.send(message);
    }

}
```

Source : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

**Note**: make sure if you are planing just try this application, email account allowing less secure apps (**Less secure app access**). Here is the link you can change that : https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

**Edit:** I am adding public version of basic mailsender project - https://github.com/ercinakcay/mailsender-public

Answer (score 6):

Is not posible without OAuth. I tried to login with the google object api gmail `ClientLogin` that way:

```
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();

ClientLogin authenticator = new ClientLogin();
authenticator.transport = transport;
authenticator.authTokenType = "mail";
authenticator.username = "user";
authenticator.password = "password";
final ClientLogin.Response response = authenticator.authenticate();
```

and the response returns this url:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps

> Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated since April 20, 2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

---

Then, if you want send a mail with java basic with gmail as provider, you can put this code:

First to all the library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And then you put a example class:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class TestMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("contact1@gmail.com, contact2@yahoo.com")
            );
            message.setSubject("Testing Gmail");
            message.setText("Hello!!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If the program throws:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at
534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.mkyong.calculator.SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:41)
```

This means you need to create a application password:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?p=InvalidSecondFactor

[image]

And then, with the application generated password, you put this password instead the other password in code:

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "puts your app password here"; // update here

        // same code...
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT :**

Problem **"Username and password not accepted"**, you can fix it by following:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=636925989304024248-4140438018&rd=1&hl=en#cantsignin

[image]