# TIBCO SMTP Sent Mail Configuration-Cert issue

Tags: ssl, tibco

I have created the process that uses sent-mail palette in Tibco BW.
I have downloaded the certificates for gmail using s_client -showcerts -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp
and configure the certificates in sent mail palette
I am getting Error-

> BW-MAIL-100019 Job-178001 Error in [Process/BloodRequest.process/Send
>   Mail] Error sending mail message. Cause:
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested
>   exception is: iaik.security.ssl.SSLException: Server certificate
>   rejected by ChainVerifier

Does anyone have an idea about a Certificate Error in Tibco BW?

Comment: What is tibco bw version ?

Comment: The tibco BW version is 5.13 .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some root certificates missing.
I suspect that you trying to replace certificates in example project https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-37939 that have outdated certificates.

instead of

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp
```

you can find/download google certificates from google web site https://pki.goog/.
First certificate from the list https://pki.goog/gtsr1/GTSR1.crt works for me.

Please note that after fixing certificates I got following error:

```
BW-MAIL-100019 Job-34000 Error in [Mail/SendMail.process/Send Mail]
Error sending mail message. Cause: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y23sm10913598iob.28 - gsmtp
```

I was able to sent email only after setting **"Allow less secure apps: ON"**
https://myaccount.google.com/u/3/lesssecureapps?pli=1  in Google account settings

[image]

just in case here are other possible reasons for  javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException :
[JavaMail with Gmail: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965251/javamail-with-gmail-535-5-7-1-username-and-password-not-accepted)